# Bootstrap 3.0 and the dreaded scrollTo & affix flicker on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've seen a lot of posts about the issues with flickering pages when using the ScrollTo.js plugin and Bootstrap. Specifically in iOS. I've tried many of the suggestions to no avail. I'm also using Bootstrap's Affix to affix a navbar once it the user scrolls to it.  I can't tell if it's the ScollTo or the Affix that is causing the flickering but the .navbar appears to jump or bounce on an iOS device.  Any ideas how to clear this up?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="66">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#top"><img src="images/logo@2x.png" width="209px" height="54px" class="logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  $('.navbar a').on('touchstart click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  target = this.hash;
  $.scrollTo(target, 1000, {'axis': 'y'});
});
```